# Get iFrame's updated value

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I submit a form with target to an iFrame. Now when I try to get the innerHTML of iFrame I get null. Here is my code:

```
<form  name="upload_form" action="" method="post" target="upload_target">
//----- other tags
</form>
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src=""></iframe>
```

The action return an id value which will be set into iFrame. Now after that when I try to get innerHTML of iFrame it shows null. While in ui I can see the id value in iFrame.

The js code:

```
alert(document.getElementById("upload_target").innerHTML);
```

How can I get the id value from iFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `contentWindow` property to acces iframe contents :

```
document.getElementById('upload_target').contentWindow.document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a html page that calls a callback function in the parrent window:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Upload Result</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var fn = parent['uploadSuccess'];
            if (fn) {
                fn(<fileId>);
            }            
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And in the parrent window:

```
window['uploadSuccess'] = function(fileId) {
   // do something with the fileId
}
```